# div fixed on the right side is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am willing to let a fixed bar on the right side of my site , plus another div is getting over and I am unable to put it aside !
Follow the link to see my problem , I'm using twitter bootstrap .

CSS :

```css
html, body { height: 100%;}
.sidebar-menu{ height:100%; background:#000; position:fixed; }
.content-wrapper{ background:#090; }
```

Markup :

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <aside class="col-sm-3 sidebar-menu">teste01</aside>
    <section class="col-sm-9 content-wrapper">teste 02</section>
</div>
```

[View the code - Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/0hKXsOG76p)

Comment: If i understand well, are you looking for something like this http://www.bootply.com/spfvtHanUU ?

Comment: Patrick LC, Yes, that was it ! What did you do differently? so put the container -fluid 100% ? more why? it is not 100% by default?

Comment: Great! yes, that's the trick, the container must be set to height 100%, it's not the default for bootstrap, container-fluid just takes full width.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: The right div is fixed

The solution is to set the container-fluid to full height also, because for bootstrap the default is to take full width ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)).

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {height: 100%;}

.sidebar-menu{ height:100%; background:#555; position:fixed}
.content-wrapper{ background:#090; float:right}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 sidebar-menu">teste01</aside>
    <section class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 content-wrapper">teste 02</section>
</div>
```

Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/77SmRLFZpE)

Comment: Ok , the more it is not fixed ! I need the black bar is fixed !

Comment: Great! You are welcome, if you think the answer is what you want you could accept it (and upvote if you think that helps). Have a nice day!

Comment: Patrick, just one more problem! When is on a lower resolution than 768px div .. the green is hiding the other! any solution?

Comment: Yes, added also col-xs-* to the sections, check: http://www.bootply.com/83e5qsiamV

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of something like this working.  http://www.bootply.com/73864

You need to use the affix module.  To make this work.